# How to remove Certificate from "IIS server certificates" from command line

Tags: iis-7, ssl-certificate

I am able to add certificates to IIS server certificates
certutil -p <> -importPFX Test.pfx"
But i am unable to remove the certificate froom the command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find the thumbprint and then pass it to certutil.exe

In PowerShell:

```
$thumbprint = (Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\MY | WHERE {$_.Subject -match "blah blah" } 
& certutil.exe -delstore my $thumbprint
```

Comment: This did not work for completely. I had to add .thumbprint to the delstore section

$thumbprint = (Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\MY | WHERE {$_.Subject -match "blah blah" } 
& certutil.exe -delstore my $thumbprint.thumbprint